# Calling Method from Separate Class to MainWindow.cs

Tags: c#, wpf

I guess doing this in VB is much easier, but how do I call a method that is another class? This is what I have inside of my Sql.cs:

```
public static MainWindow MainWindow;
public void FlLoadMembers()
    {
        SetConnection();
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlCmd = SqlCon.CreateCommand();
        const string commandText = "select firstname, lastname from members";
        SqlAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, SqlCon);
        DsMembers.Reset();
        SqlAdapter.Fill(DsMembers);
        DtMembers = DsMembers.Tables[0];
        MainWindow.lstPanelMembers.Items.Add(DtMembers);
        SqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Trying to call this in MainWindow.cs

```
private MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetVersion();
        FlLoadMembers(); //This doesn't work apparently in C#
    }
```

Comment: This is really basic steps in programming, learn to search in google !

Comment: You either need an instance of whatever class it is defined in, or it needs to be a static method and you'd have to specify the class name before it.

Comment: Oh ok. I was looking for a way to keep clean code and categorize my code into something like a Module, but those aren't in C#. Which is why I had my class setup the way it was.

Comment: What you need is a book or website to learn how to code in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlLoadMembers()` must be in a `class`. You need to create the object of that class and then you can call that function. So if your function `FlLoadMembers()` is in class named `Class1`, then you can do this:

```
Class1 obj = new Class1(); //Creating the object.
obj.FlLoadMembers();//Calling the function.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is probably best to put each on of these methods in their own Class and call them accordingly? I was used to using Modules in VB, which is why I thought this would work lol.

Comment: If you want to share same copy of a function, you can mark it as `static` and then you do not need to create objects for accessing the object. It will give you a feel of `module` in VB.

Comment: Ok, that makes it easier. Thank you! :)